# MySQL - LIMIT selects 1 less then supposed

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to LIMIT the database output with 5, but it's only selecting 4. And yes, I'm sure there's more then 4.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM lookup
            INNER JOIN lookupCategories
            ON lookup.FK_lookupCategory=lookupCategories.lookupCategoriesId
            INNER JOIN lookupType
            ON lookup.FK_lookupType=lookupType.lookupTypeId
            INNER JOIN authentication
            ON lookup.FK_lookupUserId=authentication.userId
            WHERE FK_lookupUserId='$_GET[id]'
            ORDER BY lookupId DESC
            LIMIT 5";
```

My code looks like this. What could be wrong? :)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I like how you use a 'naked' `$_GET[id]` in your SQL.

Comment: So you're saying that you removed the `LIMIT 5` from your query, ran it and you got more results or are you saying that you checked one of the tables in question and saw more than 4 records?

Comment: Off-topic, I would clean that $_GET before inserting it.

Comment: Are you sure there's 5 entries? My guess is that one of your joins is limiting the amount of rows you think are being returned.

Comment: what is happening if you do not limit the query? are you getting all expected results?

Comment: If you would read the question, I'm telling you that: Yes, im sure theres more then 4...

Comment: @N.B. If I remove the LIMIT im getting 10 entries...

Comment: Well, since I don't really trust you to have inspected everything right, I'm calling a PICNIC on this one. Computers don't randomly throw arbitrary values :>

Comment: @N.B. Well, that's your decision. I've removed the limit, and it gives me 10 entries. If I add the LIMIT it gives me 4. Now, marry your computer, smash it, and then get a life :>

Comment: @Kolind - yep, PICNIC issue, regardless of what or who I am, it's you who's with the problem in the end. Or with a PC that developed intelligence and became stubborn :>

Comment: @N.B. Hmm, I think you missed what this site is all about. To help! And I needed help with this. If you don't know what's wrong, just shut it :) Thanks.

Comment: I know what's wrong, sadly you don't have the intelligence to view the problem from a different angle. Good luck seeking help in the future, seems like you're the type that'll need it :)

Comment: @N.B. You're so good at describing yourself mate :)

Comment: You really want to flame at a website that's designed for help? If you want to throw around low level insults-lookalikes, I can give you my email and fire anything you can find at 4chan or google. Point being is that you asked for help and won't take into consideration that **you might have been wrong in your assumption**. You're not the only person who does it, we all do it, from looking at the wrong DB to the point that we think that seeing [4] when doing print_r on an array means 4 entries. What's certain is that a computer won't randomly do illogical thing. A human will.

Comment: @N.B. Well, I never said that I didn't want to assume that it was my own fault. (I found out it was). But dude, you didn't exactly throw out something like: "Would you please check again, if something is wrong with your script?". It's the way you wrote it yourself.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6655/discussion-between-kolind-and-n-b)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest that there are only 4 entries that match - to prove or disprove this, try your query without the `LIMIT` and see how many results are returned:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM lookup
        INNER JOIN lookupCategories
            ON lookup.FK_lookupCategory=lookupCategories.lookupCategoriesId
        INNER JOIN lookupType
            ON lookup.FK_lookupType=lookupType.lookupTypeId
        INNER JOIN authentication
            ON lookup.FK_lookupUserId=authentication.userId
        WHERE FK_lookupUserId='$_GET[id]';
```

Comment: for better practices's sake, please replace that '$_GET[id]' at least with an (int) $_GET[id]..

Comment: @rich.okelly If I remove the LIMIT im getting 10 entries. So, I guess it's not that.